# JMSTranslation Cannot parse file

Tags: symfony

I'm running into a very weird issue. I have 1 file with certain code that is valid only in PHP5.5+ and whenever I run the jmstranslation bundle command line to extract messages I get the error saying that file (on that specific line cannot be parsed). It's very weird because I made sure that the php version I have on my machine is 5.5+ (and everything runs just fine including the phpunit tests).

The exact error I got is

```
  [RuntimeException]
  Could not parse "Processor.php": Unexpected token '=' on line 135


  [PHPParser_Error]
  Unexpected token '=' on line 135
```

The code that caused the error:

```
if (!empty($adjustments = $this->createAdjustments($order))) 
{ 
  // the empty check above should work in PHP 5.5+
  // ... 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you assign a variable (here `$adjustments`) in the `if` test? In some cases it's useful, but in your case is it a typo, instead of the `==` operator ?

Did you try to perform the same operation in 2 steps?

```php
$adjustments = $this->createAdjustments($order);

if (!empty($adjustments)) 
{ 
  // the empty check above should work in PHP 5.5+
  // ... 
}
```

Comment: No I don't think it's a typo, I want to assign the result to adjustments then check if adjustments is empty. Of course what you proposed would work fine (and that is how it should be done in older PHP version), but in PHP 5.5 it should be possible. According to php document: Prior to PHP 5.5, empty() only supports variables; anything else will result in a parse error. In other words, the following will not work: empty(trim($name)). Instead, use trim($name) == false.

Comment: Ok, I see in the PHP documentation that PHP5.5 can use the `empty(trim($name))` syntax. But I don't see on the documentation page where an assignement can be made in the test. Anyway, since the error is triggered by `PHPParser`, I think that it's a problem with PHPParser, not PHP5 or Symfony2. So maybe you should check that PHPParser is compatible with PHP5.5 syntax or contact the developers to report this bug.

Comment: You are right, I was under the impression that this belongs to PHP5 but it seems not to be the case. I will check with the parser plugin author to see if there is any fix. I will update this question with any result I find.

Comment: this issue has been confirmed, issue also submitted to the list so that author can resolve asap https://github.com/schmittjoh/JMSTranslationBundle/issues/155